# How to efficiently select child objects through LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

In an effort to access child objects only through their aggregate roots, I am struggling to think of efficient ways to select the correct data. Could I rewrite the following to be more efficient/concise?

```
        var jobReport = db.Jobs
            .Where(j => j.JobReports.Any(jr => jr.ReportId == reportId))
            .Select(j => j.JobReports.Single(jr => jr.ReportId == reportId))
            .Single();
```

Comment: are you trying to select a Job or a JobReport? If JobReport, why don't you just do something like `db.JobReports.Single(x => x.ReportId == reportId)`?

Comment: A JobReport. And I would prefer not to access it through db.JobReports, because it isn't an aggregate root entity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you wrote would be equivalent to:

```
var jobReport = db.Jobs.SelectMany(j => j.JobReports)
                       .Single(jr => jr.ReportId == reportId);
```

Comment: No filter for `reportId`?